# Basic function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I am starting to work with MATLAB and I still don't know how to do a lot of things. I have to create a simple plot function, let's supose it is:

```
f(x)=3x+1, defined for example from -5 < x < 5
```

What I need to do is to create a function that transforms the independent variable (it's an input parameter). For example, if my function is named `plotFunction`, if execute the command `plotFunction(2x+3)` the final plotted graphic is the function:

```
f(x)=6x+10
```

Comment: I don't understand the relation between `3x+1`, `2x+3` and `6x+10` could you clarify how you get those expressions?

Comment: The input parameter of the function is placed as the x in the original function. f(x)=3(2x+3)+1=6x+10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions can be defined by the [`function`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) environment. You want a function that has no output variable, just the plot apparently.

```
function [] = plotFunction(f,minRange,maxRange)
    range = minRange:0.01:maxRange; % Create plot range, change 0.01 to w/e precision you want to attain
    figure; % Create figure
    PlotFunc = 3.*f(range)+1; % Your function
    plot(range,PlotFunc)
end
```

There's two things you need to know when trying to use other functions as 'base function': I have now set it to take steps of `0.01` this might need to be set smaller (e.g. when plotting on [-1e-4,1e-4]). You can do this by hand or use a precision switch as @efirvida used. The other thing: I call `3*f(range)+1` as `PlotFunc`. If you want to use other functions, do it there, e.g. if you want to use `cos(x)+1/3*sin(pi*x)*e^(-x))` set all the `x` to `f(x)`: `PlotFunc = cos(f(x))+1/3.*sin(pi.*f(x))*exp(-f(x)))`

Now you have to take care to call `x` as a [`function handle`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html), like so: `f = @(x)(2*x+3)`. The `@` makes it a function handle, the argument directly behind it defines the variable in the defined function, here that's `(x)`. The second set of brackets contains the actual function. Then define your range, i.e. `minRange = -5` `maxRange = 5` and call your function:

```
plotFunction(f,minRange,maxRange)
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: why `3*f(range)+1` and not just `f(range)`.  I edit my solution to look like yours, is exactly the same, but you pass the function and I pass a string and convert it to function, but thanks for your deleted comment

Comment: @efirvida because the OP wants a nested-function basically. See the updated answer

Comment: This is because the function passed as parameter had to be included in the independent variable of the original function (f(x)=3x+1). Adriaan's solutions works perfectly, you forgot this last step, but the idea was okay. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: A lot of the confusion stems from the fact that you define `x` to be a function of `x`: x(x) basically. If this solution works, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark below the vote arrows. This will signify that my answer worked for you and that you no longer need help. There is no obligation to do this however.

Answer (score 2):

My solution

file **plotFunction.m**

```
function plotFunction(f, lb, ub, precision)
    f = str2func(['@(x) ', f]);
    plot(lb:precision:ub, f(lb:precision:ub))
end
```

where `f` is string representation of function, and `lb`,`ub` the bound of the independent variable, and `precision` the precision of the plot

**run function**

```
>>> plotFunction('2*x+3', -5, 5, 0.01)
```

[image]

```
>>> plotFunction('6*x+10 ', -5, 5, 0.01)
```

[image]